# How to develop two different menu bars for a website (one for all users, and the other one for the Admin) in ASP.NET webfroms?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I am developing a web application in ASP.NET. The menu/ navigation bar is at the top of the website. Now, I want to create the Administrative tasks and since I have enough space in the menu bar, I will add a new tab/ element to the menu called Admin which will appear only to the Admin. The problem now is: to add this element, I need to change a little bit in the style of the menu. The menu style is placed in a separate CSS file and it is different from the CSS file of the whole website. By doing this, I will change the style of the menu for all users and what I want is just displaying these changes to the Admin not to all users. Therefore, how to do that? Is there any way to do that?

***The menu bar is implemented inside the Site.master page. Also, I am using Windows Authentication not Forms Authentication. No need for Forms Authentication, because the website will be only used inside the company.***

Please provide me with example (if any)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ASP.NET role provider which integrates with some of the built in ASP.NET controls like Menu and TreeView.

See [Recipe: Implementing Role-Based Security with ASP.NET 2.0 using Windows Authentication and SQL Server](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/Recipe_3A00_-Implementing-Role_2D00_Based-Security-with-ASP.NET-2.0-using-Windows-Authentication-and-SQL-Server.aspx)  for some ideas.

[ASP.NET Site-Map Security Trimming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178428%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) describes roles and security trimming.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to keep two separate CSS files, one for menu for all users and other for admin users only and based on the logged in load the css file dynamically:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        HtmlLink cssLink = new HtmlLink();

        if(User is Admin)
            cssLink.Href = "~/styles/admin_menu.css";
        else
            cssLink.Href = "~/styles/users_menu.css";

        cssLink.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");        
        cssLink.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
        Header.Controls.Add(cssMasterLink);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that besides asking how to separate CSS files for the 2 roles, you are also asking how to produce different menus depending on the role.

One approach I've used is to have a MenuControl.ascx. Inside that MenuControl, I'd do something like this:

```
<%  if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin")){%>
     <li class="myclass"><a class="link" href="#Product">Admin</a>
<%}%>
```

Of course this implies that you have implemented Forms authentication and that you have implemented [IPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.aspx) but the idea is the same regardless of how you implemented roles on your app.

Answer (score 0):

You could create two different pages, one for admins and one for everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use WebUserControl. One for the Admin and one for All users then use "@ Reference" directive in your main page or masterpage then set your condition which usercontrol to be rendered.